# Connecting to Cloudera VM from my desktop

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera

I downloaded the Cloudera VM on my Windows 7 laptop to play around.  I
am trying to connect to the Hadoop instance running in the VM from
Windows.  I did an ifconfig and got the IP address of the VM.  I can
connect to the web interfaces running in the VM from Firefox running
on my Windows box so i know i can connect at least to that.

So next, i tried to connect to Hadoop from Java.

```
public class FileSystemWriter
{

static
        {
                URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory( new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory() );
        }

        public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
        {
                String uri = "hdfs://192.168.171.128/user";
                Configuration conf = new Configuration();

                System.out.println( "uri: " + uri );

                FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get( URI.create( uri ), conf );
       }

}
```

But i get errors.

**uri: hdfs://192.168.171.128/user**

```
Aug 9, 2011 8:29:26 AM org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection
handleConnectionFailure
INFO: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.171.128:8020. Already tried
0 time(s).
Aug 9, 2011 8:29:28 AM org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection
handleConnectionFailure
INFO: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.171.128:8020. Already tried
1 time(s).
Aug 9, 2011 8:29:30 AM org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection
handleConnectionFailure
INFO: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.171.128:8020. Already tried
2 time(s).
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm also having the exact same issue on os x!  I've been stuck for a while. I posted this on the cloudera getsatisfaction web forum.... Go there and up vote it!!!  http://getsatisfaction.com/cloudera/topics/_amateur_question_external_connection_to_the_cloudera_vm

Answer (score 2):

First, try to connect over hftp .

```
        uri = "hftp://172.16.xxx.xxx:50070/";

        System.out.println( "uri: " + uri );           
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get( URI.create( uri ), conf );
        fs.printStatistics();
```

If you see something (no exceptions), then you are connected.

If you do not, then your problem is not HDFS, but rather, your problem is that you have a bad ip, or hadoop isn't running, or your ports are blocked... etc...

Comment: its working with hftp but can't get it working via hdfs. Can you suggest a reason?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your Namenode is listening on port 8020. You can check with this command:

   ```
   hadoop fs -ls hdfs://namenode(ip):8020
   ```
2. If this check fails, type `vim HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml` and see your namenode port in this entry of `fs.default.name`.
3. Change your java code:

   ```
   String uri = "hdfs://192.168.171.128:portOfNameNode/user";
   ```